# Writing to File, Stream Closed error, Java

Tags: java

I'm currently doing a project in java for collage and I've riden into a bit of a problem and hope that one of you can shine light on what I cannot see. Below is the code I use to write an Array[] to a file. The array itself is a [100]. The problem I'm having is that I cannot understand what the stack is telling you or how to solve the problem and stop it. The file it is calling is already created by another class and I've checked to confirm it

```
public void writeGridToFile() throws IOException {
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("D:/GridArrayFile.txt");
            try {
                for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
                    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
                    bw.write(GridArray[i]);
                    bw.close();
                }
            }

            catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("Error");
            }
            finally {
                //TODO
                System.out.println("Finished");
            }
    }
```

This is the exception stack being printed

```
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.ensureOpen(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.write(Unknown Source)
at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.write(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedWriter.flushBuffer(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedWriter.close(Unknown Source)
at playgame.writeGridToFile(playgame.java:195)
at playgame.CreateFile(playgame.java:183)
at playgame$1.actionPerformed(playgame.java:73)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Hope you  can find the problem, also as a side note if this is a easy quick let me off I've only been using java for about 1 1/2 years and its all still very new to me.

Comment: You're closing the `BufferedWriter` in the loop, which is then closing the underlying `FileWriter`... so in the next iteration the `FileWriter` is closed.

Comment: as a sidenote: `try(BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("D:/GridArrayFile.txt"))) {...Your Code}` would be the java 7+ way to do it, 
As in every case, abnormal or normal completion, the Stream will be closed

Comment: @SomeJavaGuy thank's that also gets the code working as well. The only problem I'm having is the the file content outputted is nothing like the data held inside of the array. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void writeGridToFile() throws IOException {
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("D:/GridArrayFile.txt");
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        try {
           for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
                bw.write(GridArray[i]);
           }
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("Error");
        }
        finally {
                bw.close();
                System.out.println("Finished");
        }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks that fixed the expection problem also but the output in the file looks like '                              ' which is weird due the values of the array are 0 or 1 but yet no numbers are being displayed.

Comment: what type of values `GridArray` contains?

Comment: int[] GridArray = new int[100]; it only holds int's they mainly consist of 1 and 0's

Comment: Use can use `bw.newLine()` after `bw.write()` to output each index at different line.

Comment: I've fixed the problem with the output it was related to me not changing the Int to a string before outputting. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

The statement inside your loop:

```
bw.close();
```

will close the `FileWriter fw` as well. Maybe you are looking for something like this?

```
public static void main(String[] args)
throws IOException {
    int[] gridArray = new int[] { 'H', 'u', 'r', 'r', 'a', 'y', '!' };
    try (FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("gridArrayFile.txt")) {
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        for (int i = 0; i < gridArray.length; i++) {
            bw.write(gridArray[i]);
        }
        bw.flush();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Error");
    } finally {
        System.out.println("Finished");
    }
}
```

I did and run and afterwards the file `gridArrayFile.txt` got created and contained the string `Hurray!`.

Comment: Right well that fixed the exception problem. But nothing is changing in the file so something must be wrong with the writer. Would you happen to have any ideas.

Comment: You need to `bw.flush()` the content before your close your writer. Otherwise buffered content will not be written to the file.

Comment: I've tried that but it still has the same strange output would it have anything to do with the fact my Array stores Int?

Comment: Managed to solve it was mentioned in the problem above

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for help everyone below is the code that was the fixed solution to this problem.

```
public void writeGridToFile() throws IOException {
    try(BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("D:/GridArrayFile.txt"))) {
        for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
            bw.write(Integer.toString(GridArray[i]));
       }
        bw.flush();
     }
     catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Error");
     }
     finally {
            System.out.println("Finished");
     }
}
```